# Displaying HTML content in BrowserField not working perfectly in blackberry

Tags: html, browser, blackberry, field

i solved my problem which i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713177/problem-in-parsing-xml-in-blackberry). Actualy the problem is not exactly in parsing, but problem is in url creation. :)

Now i have an another problem, i.e. data which i get using parsing have HTML tags, I used BrowserField to display HTML content. but this works fine in simulator, and not running perfectly on device...

problem facing on device is FONT SIZE problem.

can anybody help me to solve this problem

Thanx in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to skip Html tags...

```
public String HtmlRemove(String s)
{ 
    char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
    boolean tag = false; for (int i=0; i<cs.length; i++) 
    { 
        switch(cs[i]) 
        {
        case '<': 
                if ( ! tag) 
            { 
            tag = true;
            break;
            }
        case '>': 
            if (tag) 
            {
            tag = false;
            break; 
            }
        break;
        case '&':
            if ( ! tag) 
            { 
            tag = true;
            break;
            }
        case ';': 
            if (tag) 
            {
            tag = false;
            break; 
            }
        break;
        default:
            if ( ! tag) sb.append(cs[i]); 
        }
    }
    return sb.toString(); 
}
```

This will surely help you

Comment: hey deepika thanks 4 your reply. yeah you r right, my problem get solved with your this code snippet :)